# Can't resolve type declarations despite having found the type declarations

Tags: typescript

When I run `tsc` on my project, it reports

```
src/app/home-behavior.ts(8,30): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'jqueryui'. 'C:/myProjectPath/src/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/jqueryui` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jqueryui';`
```

But I already have @types/jqueryui installed, and `tsc --traceResolution` even shows

```
======== Resolving type reference directive 'jqueryui', containing file 'C:/myProjectPath/__inferred type names__.ts', root directory 'C:/myProjectPath/node_modules/@types'. ========
Resolving with primary search path 'C:/myProjectPath/node_modules/@types'.
Found 'package.json' at 'C:/myProjectPath/node_modules/@types/jqueryui/package.json'.
'package.json' does not have a 'typings' field.
'package.json' does not have a 'types' field.
File 'C:/myProjectPath/node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
Resolving real path for 'C:/myProjectPath/node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts', result 'C:/myProjectPath/node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts'.
======== Type reference directive 'jqueryui' was successfully resolved to 'C:/myProjectPath/node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts', primary: true. ========
```

So it resolved the definition but still can't find the definition?

---

Typescript version 2.4.1. Using AMD-style loading with requirejs. My jquery-ui typings are from npm module `@types/jqueryui`. My directory structure is

```
projectroot
+ src
| + app
| | + home-behavior.ts
| + lib
|   + jquery
|   | + dist
|   |   + jquery.js
|   + jquery-ui
|     + jquery-ui.js
+ node_modules
| + @types
|   + jquery
|   | + index.d.ts
|   + jqueryui
|     + index.d.ts
+ tsconfig.json
```

My tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "classic",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "paths": {
      "jqueryui": [
        "src/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"
      ],
      "*": [
        "src/lib/*"
      ]
    },
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/app"
  ]
}
```

The reference in home-behavior.ts is

```
import { Autocomplete } from "jqueryui";
```

(Originally I referred to the module as "jquery-ui/jquery-ui", but since tsc was already resolving "jqueryui" I changed the module name to match, on the theory that that would help.)

Comment: The types for jQueryUI does not export any members. So you can try doing just `import  "jquery"; import  "jqueryui";` and use it as `$("selector").autocomplete(...)`.

Comment: I'll give it a try. For reference, though, https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/environments/amd/ says that I should be able to do `require([ "jquery-ui/autocomplete" ], function( autocomplete ) { ... }`. I've been trying to get as close to that as I can with Typescript.

Comment: Yeah, that works. So if I wanted to do this AMD-style I'd need to revise the typings?

Comment: Yes you will have to update the typings. And AFAIK to use it like that you have to use the source from GitHub not the version distributed via npm.

Comment: Thanks. Write it up as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do `import { Autocomplete } from "jqueryui";` since the typings for jQuery UI does not export any members. You can just do:

```
import  "jquery";
import "jqueryui";

$("selector").autocomplete(...);
```

And if you want to use it like it is mentioned [here](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/environments/amd/) you have to use the jQuery UI library from source and update the TypeScript typings.